# angular observer value assignment

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to angular and I am trying to use the observer pattern to access my fastAPI. I'm confused as to what is going on inside the callback that is passed to the subscribe function. Here's the code:

```
export class EmployeeAccessRightsComponent implements OnInit {

  data: any = {};
  show = true;
  constructor(private service: EmployeeAccessRightsService) {
    this.service.get_employee_access_rights().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.data = data;
        // Option 1: These 3 lines work
        console.log(this.data); 
        console.log(data); //same output as previous line
        console.log(this.data['access_rights']); 
        
        // Option 2: This gives an error
        // console.log(data['access_rights']); 
        // error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"access_rights"' can't be used to index type 'Object'.
        // Property 'access_rights' does not exist on type 'Object'.
        console.log(typeof data);
        console.log(typeof this.data);
      });
}
```

My question is why does option 2 not work? I've check the type of the variables and they both are of type `object`. What is going on with the assignment `this.data = data`?

Edit: When printed to console, `data` looks like

```
{access_rights: Array(6)}
```

Edit 2:
`get_employee_access_rights` returns an Observable object.

This is the service that was used. It accesses a local API that returns what I think is a JSON (it's an HttpClient GET method as you can see)

```
export class EmployeeAccessRightsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  get_employee_access_rights(employeeID: number = 1) {
    let url = 'http://localhost:8000/employee-access-rights/' + employeeID;
    return this.http.get(url);
  }
}
```

Also, I cannot access `data` using operator[] at all so `JSON.parse()` won't work.

`data` has a `toString` property that returns the following:

```
ƒ () {
        if (typeof Promise === 'function' && this instanceof Promise) {
            return PROMISE_OBJECT_TO_STRING;
        }
        return originalObjectToString.call(this);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show `get_employee_access_rights`?

Comment: `get_employee_access_rights()` return an object, this object have a type or return an any?

Comment: Can you try `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data['access_rights'])))`  or just  `console.log(JSON.parse(data['access_rights']))`?

Answer (score 0):

Your error is unrelated to Angular, and is caused by TypeScript reading `data` as Object, because it is typed as `implicit any`, so the TypeScript compiler cannot infer anything about which properties it may have.

Try

```js
data: {[k: string]: any} = {}

constructor(private service: EmployeeAccessRightsService) {
  this.service.get_employee_access_rights().subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
      console.log(this.data["access_rights"]
  })
}
```

Similarly, Option 2 does not work because the data in your `.subscribe(data => {...})` is *implicitly* any, which makes TypeScript a bit unhappy when you attempt to access its properties using bracket notation.

You can alleviate this by moving the type information from your class, into the callback:

```js
.subscribe((data: {[key: string]: any}) => {...})
```

Naturally, it would be better for your code maintenance if you explicitly typed the expected response from your API, but that is neither here nor there.